# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method

Tags: c#

A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method

```
// Create MyClass object
DatePickerDisigner objDatePicker = new DatePickerDisigner();
// Get the Type information.
Type myTypeObj = objDatePicker.GetType();
// Get Method Information.
MethodInfo myMethodInfo = myTypeObj.GetMethod("AddViews");
//Defining the parameter
object[] mParam = new object[] { 5, 10 };
// Invoking the method 
myMethodInfo.Invoke(myClassObj, mParam);
```

*I am getting error while getting the type of an object.
Can anyone plz help me.

#### Update regarding the comment:

```
namespace SitefinityWebApp.Corticon.FormControls.ChoiceFieldDesigner 
{ 
  public class DatePickerDisigner : FormTextBoxDesigner 
  { 
    protected override string ScriptDescriptorTypeName 
    { 
      get 
      { 
         return typeof(ContentViewDesignerBase).FullName; 
      } 
   } 

   protected override void AddViews(Dictionary<string, ControlDesignerView> views) 
   { 
     base.AddViews(views);
     var corticonView = new CorticonView();
     views.Add(corticonView.ViewName, corticonView); 
   } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Where do you have this code? Inside a method, inside the constructor or somewhere else?

Comment: You should enclose your code in method/property/constructor.

Comment: Did you mean to pass array instead of Dictionary as a parameter?